# QST: error while using pickle to load the files

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I am getting the below error while using pickle to load the files on kaggle.

It has worked for everyone, but it is not working for me. The file path is correct.

Thank you for your help.

My code:

```
%%time
import pickle
#using one of the validation sets composed by tito

cv2_train = pd.read_pickle("../input/riiid-cross-validation-files/cv2_train.pickle")['row_id']
cv2_valid = pd.read_pickle("../input/riiid-cross-validation-files/cv2_valid.pickle")['row_id']
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/pickle.py in read_pickle(filepath_or_buffer, compression)
    167     if not isinstance(fp_or_buf, str) and compression == "infer":
    168         compression = None
--> 169     f, fh = get_handle(fp_or_buf, "rb", compression=compression, is_text=False)
    170 
    171     # 1) try standard library Pickle

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors)
    497         else:
    498             # Binary mode
--> 499             f = open(path_or_buf, mode)
    500         handles.append(f)
    501 

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../input/riiid-cross-validation-files/cv2_train.pickle'
```

Comment: The error message says that the file is not where you expect it to be. A relative path is relative to the current working directory of the process. If you start the script with `python script.py`, no problem it is your current path. But if you use an IDE it is where the IDE sets it.

Comment: first `import os`, then `directory, scriptname=os.path.split(__file__)`, now you can use `pd.read_pickle(directory + "\\input\\riiid-cross-validation-files\\cv2_valid.pickle"`

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei that is not working either. Error: NameError: name '__file__' is not defined

Comment: @SergeBallesta dask method with the same path works, but pickle does not. This one works: train = dd.read_csv("../input/riiid-test-answer-prediction/train.csv", dtype=dtypes).compute()